# calling class function while defining variable

Tags: java, c++

In java you can for example write:

```
public static final Material WOOD = (new Material(MapColor.WOOD)).setBurning();
```

how can I write this in c++?

```
static Material * WOOD = new Material(MapColor::WOOD)....
```

I would like to avoid any Init call or some sort.
Best would be to do it in one like like in Java.

Comment: It would be better to explain what you are try to do, so C++ developers who don't know java could help you.

Comment: *In java you can for example write:* -- C++ is not Java.  What is the code supposed to do?  Whatever it is, write the code in C++, pretending Java does not exist.  If you go down the road of trying to write C++ that looks like Java, you will end up with code that is hard-to-maintain, possibly has bugs and memory leaks, and in general, will look weird to a C++ programmer.

Comment: I want to create a Material an call a function setBurning return the changed Material

Answer (score 1):

First of all, in C++ you don't have to use `new` to create objects. And you should try to avoid pointers.

*Exactly* what to do in this case depends very much on what `setBurning` is returning, but if it returns a `Material` object by value (which I would recommend) then you can do something very similar:

```
static Material WOOD = Material(MapColor::WOOD).setBurning();
```

The expression `Material(MapColor::WOOD)` creates a temporary `Material` object, and then you use that object to call its `setBurning` function, which returns a new `Material` object that you save in the variable `WOOD`.

Comment: First of all thanks
I need to use pointers as I have classes inheriting Material

I have another problem when I init them in class
I get the message a member with an in-class initializer must be const

Comment: @KayHennig So don't init them in class. It's prefectly OK to declare in the class, and define outside the class (in fact that's the traditional way). Nothing like Java, but then C++ is not Java.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems you are looking for code like this

```
// header file
class Something
{
    static Material* WOOD;
};

// source file
Material* Something::WOOD = new Material(MapColor::WOOD);
```

This is perfectly normal C++ code, but not something you find in Java.

Comment: I have this set up now
```
class Material
{
   static Material * WOOD;
}

//source
Material * Material::WOOD = new Material(MapColor::WOOD);
```
but I would like to have 

```
Material * Material::WOOD = new Material(MapColor::WOOD).setBurning();
```
but don't know how to do it

Comment: Simplest way would be to define a constructor for Meterial that allows you to set the burning property. You could then use that constructor from your initialization code.